# Assigning UIColor standard color in Objective-C

Tags: ios, objective-c, uikit, uicolor, ios-darkmode

I am trying to change the colour of the FSCalendarStandardSeparatorColor UIColor variable from lightGray with 60% opacity to UIColor.separator. I am wanting to do this since this library was made before light/dark mode capability and I am wanting to allow for that by using UIKit Standard Colour.

**#define FSCalendarStandardSeparatorColor   [[UIColor lightGrayColor] colorWithAlphaComponent:0.60]**

When I change this to

**#define FSCalendarStandardSeparatorColor   [UIColor separator]**

I get the error

Arc Semantic Issue
No known class method for selector 'separator'

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

#pragma mark - Constants

CG_EXTERN CGFloat const FSCalendarStandardHeaderHeight;
CG_EXTERN CGFloat const FSCalendarStandardWeekdayHeight;
CG_EXTERN CGFloat const FSCalendarStandardMonthlyPageHeight;
CG_EXTERN CGFloat const FSCalendarStandardWeeklyPageHeight;
CG_EXTERN CGFloat const FSCalendarStandardCellDiameter;
CG_EXTERN CGFloat const FSCalendarStandardSeparatorThickness;
CG_EXTERN CGFloat const FSCalendarAutomaticDimension;
CG_EXTERN CGFloat const FSCalendarDefaultBounceAnimationDuration;
CG_EXTERN CGFloat const FSCalendarStandardRowHeight;
CG_EXTERN CGFloat const FSCalendarStandardTitleTextSize;
CG_EXTERN CGFloat const FSCalendarStandardSubtitleTextSize;
CG_EXTERN CGFloat const FSCalendarStandardWeekdayTextSize;
CG_EXTERN CGFloat const FSCalendarStandardHeaderTextSize;
CG_EXTERN CGFloat const FSCalendarMaximumEventDotDiameter;

UIKIT_EXTERN NSInteger const FSCalendarDefaultHourComponent;
UIKIT_EXTERN NSInteger const FSCalendarMaximumNumberOfEvents;

UIKIT_EXTERN NSString * const FSCalendarDefaultCellReuseIdentifier;
UIKIT_EXTERN NSString * const FSCalendarBlankCellReuseIdentifier;
UIKIT_EXTERN NSString * const FSCalendarInvalidArgumentsExceptionName;

CG_EXTERN CGPoint const CGPointInfinity;
CG_EXTERN CGSize const CGSizeAutomatic;

#if TARGET_INTERFACE_BUILDER
#define FSCalendarDeviceIsIPad NO
#else
#define FSCalendarDeviceIsIPad [[UIDevice currentDevice].model hasPrefix:@"iPad"]
#endif

#define FSCalendarStandardSelectionColor   FSColorRGBA(31,119,219,1.0)
#define FSCalendarStandardTodayColor       FSColorRGBA(198,51,42 ,1.0)
#define FSCalendarStandardTitleTextColor   FSColorRGBA(14,69,221 ,1.0)
#define FSCalendarStandardEventDotColor    FSColorRGBA(31,119,219,0.75)

#define FSCalendarStandardLineColor        [[UIColor lightGrayColor] colorWithAlphaComponent:0.30]
#define FSCalendarStandardSeparatorColor   [[UIColor lightGrayColor] colorWithAlphaComponent:0.60]

#define FSColorRGBA(r,g,b,a) [UIColor colorWithRed:r/255.0 green:g/255.0 blue:b/255.0 alpha:a]
#define FSCalendarInAppExtension [[[NSBundle mainBundle] bundlePath] hasSuffix:@".appex"]

#define FSCalendarFloor(c) floorf(c)
#define FSCalendarRound(c) roundf(c)
#define FSCalendarCeil(c) ceilf(c)
#define FSCalendarMod(c1,c2) fmodf(c1,c2)

#define FSCalendarHalfRound(c) (FSCalendarRound(c*2)*0.5)
#define FSCalendarHalfFloor(c) (FSCalendarFloor(c*2)*0.5)
#define FSCalendarHalfCeil(c) (FSCalendarCeil(c*2)*0.5)

#define FSCalendarUseWeakSelf __weak __typeof__(self) FSCalendarWeakSelf = self;
#define FSCalendarUseStrongSelf __strong __typeof__(self) self = FSCalendarWeakSelf;


#pragma mark - Deprecated

#define FSCalendarDeprecated(instead) DEPRECATED_MSG_ATTRIBUTE(" Use " # instead " instead")

static inline void FSCalendarSliceCake(CGFloat cake, NSInteger count, CGFloat *pieces) {
    CGFloat total = cake;
    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
        NSInteger remains = count - i;
        CGFloat piece = FSCalendarRound(total/remains*2)*0.5;
        total -= piece;
        pieces[i] = piece;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should be `[UIColor separatorColor]` in Objective-C.

Also, be aware that it's only available starting from iOS 13. So you need to guard accordingly.

Comment: Thank you! This got it work. However, UIColor separatorColor colour in Objective-C for one of my viewControllers appears different than the UIColor separator colour in swift in the other viewController. I have them at the same borderWidth and opacity. Would you know why that is?

Comment: The `separatorColor` is not 100% opaque: For light, it has 0.29 alpha and for dark 0.6. So it will look different on different backgrounds.

Comment: Oh. Then is separatorColor still dynamic like the rest of the iOS 13 Adaptable Colours   being different for dark/light mode and high/normal contrast? The UIColor.separator in the Swift viewController adapts to the different settings.

Comment: Also, the Objective-C UIColor separatorColor at 1.0 opacity looks lighter than the Swift UIColor separator, so I don't think reducing the opacity will help.

Comment: Yes, it's one of the "new" (in iOS 13) dynamic system colors that will adapt to the system theme.

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/4apdl9l You can see the bottom Swift UIColor.separator border is darker than the second bottom Objective-C [UIColor separatorColor] border

Comment: There shouldn't be a difference. Maybe you can print both colors in the debugger and check for differences.

Comment: Okay. I printed both of them Swift UI.Color.separator and the assigned variable is 


<CGColor **0x280282b20** > [<CGColorSpace **0x2802bf360** > (kCGColorSpaceICCBased; kCGColorSpaceModelRGB; sRGB IEC61966-2.1; extended range)] (0.329412 0.329412 0.345098 0.6)) 


Objective-C [UIColor separatorColor] and the assigned variable is not the same 

<CGColor **0x28054dce0** > [<CGColorSpace **0x280572d00** > (kCGColorSpaceICCBased; kCGColorSpaceModelRGB; sRGB IEC61966-2.1; extended range)] ( 0.329412 0.329412 0.345098 0.6 ) 


How is this possible and how do I make them the same?

Comment: If I also set the background colour ie. _topBorder.backgroundColor = [UIColor separatorColor].CGColor; then it looks the same in light mode but does not help for dark mode. This may be just avoiding the root of the issue completely.

Comment: Okay! I think I was changing the CALayer opacity when initializing it at 0.5, so probably setting the opacity to half what it's supposed to be even though the opacity it's set colour was what it was supposed to be.